# Using templateUrl in displaying div with image

Tags: css, angular

I am starting to learn angular2 and I want to have a header with a picture on it.

Here is my heading.component.html

```
<div class="heading">
    <img src="../images/header.jpg"/>
</div>
```

Here is my heading.component.ts

```
import {Component} from 'angular2/core';

@Component({
    selector: 'header',
    templateUrl: './heading.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['../style.css']
})
export class HeadingComponent { }
```

and here is my app.component.ts

```
import {Component} from 'angular2/core';
import {HeadingComponent} from './heading.component';

@Component({
    selector: 'my-app',
    template: `
    <header>fgsdgf</header>
    `,
    styleUrls: ['../style.css']
})
export class AppComponent { }
```

There is nothing shown in the browser. Can you give me an idea on how can I show the image? Thanks

Comment: Not AngularJS... so angularjs tag is not appopriate

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change your `app.component.ts` with this code :-

```
import {Component} from 'angular2/core';
import {HeadingComponent} from './heading.component';
@Component({
    selector: 'my-app',
    template: `
    <header>fgsdgf</header>
    `,
    styleUrls: ['../style.css'],
    directives: [HeadingComponent]
})
export class AppComponent { }
```

you need to add the `header` in the directives list before using it. so add this in the list of directives of your component.

Comment: nice! I forgot the directives part. this solves my issue. thanks!